# Bringing an SQL Function ReturnValue to Front End Form ListBox

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-function

I have a form with a button and a list box. The Code for button is as shown below

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim dc As New DataTestDataContext
    Dim x As List(Of SplitResult)

    x = dc.Split("1, 2, 3, 4", ",")
    ListBox1.Items.Add(x)

  End Sub
```

Im using a dbml file that has my function "Split" within it. The code for my split function is as shown below

```
 <FunctionAttribute(Name:="dbo.Split", IsComposable:=true)>  _
 Public Function Split(<Parameter(Name:="String", DbType:="VarChar(MAX)")> ByVal [string] As String, <Parameter(Name:="Delimiter", DbType:="Char(1)")> ByVal delimiter As System.Nullable(Of Char)) As IQueryable(Of SplitResult)
    Return Me.CreateMethodCallQuery(Of SplitResult)(Me, CType(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod, MethodInfo), [string], delimiter)
End Function
```

The function takes two parameters. A string and a delimeter. My chosen delimiter is a comma

The code for my SQL function is as shown below

```
 ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@String varchar(MAX), @Delimiter char(1))       
 returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(MAX))       
 as       
 begin      
declare @idx int       
declare @slice varchar(8000)       

select @idx = 1       
    if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

while @idx!= 0       
begin       
    set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
    if @idx!=0       
        set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
    else       
        set @slice = @String       

    if(len(@slice)>0)  
        insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)       

    set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
    if len(@String) = 0 break       
end  

 return
```

Ive tested the SQL Function and it works properly, i would just like to know how to get the return value from the function to my listbox. When i run the function alone, the result is in table format as shown below

```
 items
 |1|
 |2|
 |3|
 |4|
```

Thanks ahead of time

Comment: Have you tried any code to connect to the database and execute your function? Please show that code. I dont see why you could not use a DataReader or DataAdapter against your function. If you cannot, create a SP that works as a go-between and calls the function.

Comment: Im using a dbml file so that is my connection to the database. How would i use a datareader?